# Placing a Smaller Texture2D into a larger one

Tags: c#, xna, textures, monogame

Similar to many programs that take a tiled map, like that in the game Terraria, and turn the map into a single picture of the entire map, I am trying to do something similar. The problem is, my block textures are in a single large texture atlas and are referenced by index, and I am having trouble taking the color data from a single block and placing it into the correct place in the larger texture.

This is my code so far.

Getting the source from the index (this code works):

```
public static Rectangle GetSourceForIndex(int index, Texture2D tex)
    {
        int dim = tex.Width / TEXTURE_MAP_DIM;

        int startx = index % TEXTURE_MAP_DIM;
        int starty = index / TEXTURE_MAP_DIM;

        return new Rectangle(startx * dim, starty * dim, dim, dim);
    }
```

Getting the texture at the index (Where the problems start):

```
public static Texture2D GetTextureAtIndex(int index, Texture2D tex)
    {
        Rectangle source = GetSourceForIndex(index, tex);
        Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(_device, source.Width, source.Height);

        Color[] colors = new Color[tex.Width * tex.Height];
        tex.GetData<Color>(colors);
        Color[] colorData = new Color[source.Width * source.Height];

        for (int x = 0; x < source.Width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < source.Height; y++)
            {
                colorData[x + y * source.Width] = colors[x + source.X + (y + source.Y) * tex.Width];
            }
        }

        texture.SetData<Color>(colorData);
        return texture;
    }
```

Putting the texture into the larger picture (this is completely wrong I'm sure):

```
private void doSave()
    {
        int texWidth = this._rWidth * Region.REGION_DIM * 16;
        int texHeight = this._rHeight * Region.REGION_DIM * 16;

        Texture2D picture = new Texture2D(Game.GraphicsDevice, texWidth, texHeight);
        Color[] pictureData = new Color[picture.Width * picture.Height];

        for (int blockX = 0; blockX < texWidth / 16; blockX++)
        {
            for (int blockY = 0; blockY < texHeight / 16; blockY++)
            {
                Block b = this.GetBlockAt(blockX, blockY);
                Texture2D toCopy = TextureManager.GetTextureAtIndex(b.GetIndexBasedOnMetadata(b.GetMetadataForSurroundings(this, blockX, blockY)), b.GetTextureFile());
                Color[] copyData = new Color[toCopy.Width * toCopy.Height];
                Rectangle source = new Rectangle(blockX * 16, blockY * 16, 16, 16);
                toCopy.GetData<Color>(copyData);

                for (int x = 0; x < source.Width; x++)
                {
                    for (int y = 0; y < source.Height; y++)
                    {
                        pictureData[x + source.X + (y + source.Y) * picture.Width] = copyData[x + y * source.Width];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        picture.SetData<Color>(pictureData);

        string fileName = "picture" + DateTime.Now.ToString(@"MM\-dd\-yyyy-h\-mm-tt");
        FileStream stream = File.Open(this.GetSavePath() + @"Pictures\" + fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
        picture.SaveAsPng(stream, picture.Width, picture.Height);
```

I can't find any good descriptions on how to properly convert between the texture and a one dimensional color array. It would be much easier if I knew how to easily and properly place a square of colors into a larger two dimensional texture.

TL;DR: How do you put a smaller Texture into a larger texture?

Comment: Are you trying to do something in real time here? Or do you just want to assemble the bigger texture for later use in a real time application. Because I assume what you *really* want is to assemble the tiles at runtime. Putting all your tiles into a large texture kills every benefit of a tile system.

Comment: When you draw your tiles you can use the spritebatch Source rectangle parameter

Comment: I am making a larger picture because I thought it would be interesting to be able to get an image of your entire world. The game is still using a tile based system. Its purely for fun, it's not functional at all. What I need to know is how the Texture2D system works in order to compile one image out of the entire map.

Answer (score 0):

Create a RenderTarget2D the size of you largest texture and set it to active. Draw the large texture then draw the smaller one. Set the reference to the original texture to the RenderTarget2D you just drew to.

```
int texWidth = this._rWidth * Region.REGION_DIM * 16;
int texHeight = this._rHeight * Region.REGION_DIM * 16;

_renderTarget = new RenderTarget2D(GraphicsDevice, texWidth, texHeight);
GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(_renderTarget);
GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Transparent);

_spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, BlendState.Opaque);

for (int blockX = 0; blockX < texWidth / 16; blockX++)
{
    for (int blockY = 0; blockY < texHeight / 16; blockY++)
    {
         _spriteBatch.Draw(
            TextureManager.GetTextureAtIndex(b.GetIndexBasedOnMetadata(b.GetMetadataForSurroundings(this, blockX, blockY)), b.GetTextureFile()), 
         new Rectangle(blockX * 16, blockY * 16, 16, 16), 
         Color.White);
     }
}

_spriteBatch.End()

GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);
var picture = _renderTarget;
```

Comment: I tried using your method, but I'm getting a "Framebuffer Incomplete" error at the line "GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(renderTarget)".

Comment: What platform are developing for? And does it work with pure XNA and not monogame?